# What is the right global_work_size and local_work_size in Matrix Multiplication in OpenCL?

Tags: java, opencl, gpgpu, matrix-multiplication, jocl

I'm doing matrix multiplication in JOCL a Java bindings to OpenCL. The problem, I got an error

`Exception in thread "main" org.jocl.CLException: CL_INVALID_WORK_ITEM_SIZE
    at org.jocl.CL.checkResult(CL.java:787)
    at org.jocl.CL.clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(CL.java:20802)
    at org.jocl.samples.JOCLSample.main(JOCLSample.java:150)`

Here's the code:

```
package org.jocl.samples;

import static org.jocl.CL.*;

import org.jocl.*;
import static java.lang.System.nanoTime;


public class JOCLSample
{
    /**
     * The source code of the OpenCL program to execute
     */
    private static String programSource =
    "__kernel void "+
    "matrixMul(__global float* C,"+ 
    "          __global float* A,"+ 
    "          __global float* B,"+ 
    "          int wA, int wB)"+
    "{"+

       "int tx = get_global_id(0);"+ 
       "int ty = get_global_id(1);"+

       "float value = 0;"+
       "for (int k = 0; k < wA; ++k)"+
       "{"+
       "   float elementA = A[ty * wA + k];"+
       "   float elementB = B[k * wB + tx];"+
       "   value += elementA * elementB;"+
       "}"+

      "C[ty * wA + tx] = value;"+
    "}";



    /**
     * The entry point of this sample
     * 
     * @param args Not used
     */
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        // Create input- and output data 
        int n = 10;
        float srcArrayA[] = new float[n];
        float srcArrayB[] = new float[n];
        float dstArray[] = new float[n];
        for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
            srcArrayA[i] = i;
            srcArrayB[i] = i;
        }
        Pointer srcA = Pointer.to(srcArrayA);
        Pointer srcB = Pointer.to(srcArrayB);
        Pointer dst = Pointer.to(dstArray);

        // The platform, device type and device number
        // that will be used
        final int platformIndex = 0;
        final long deviceType = CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL;
        final int deviceIndex = 0;

        // Enable exceptions and subsequently omit error checks in this sample
        CL.setExceptionsEnabled(true);

        // Obtain the number of platforms
        int numPlatformsArray[] = new int[1];
        clGetPlatformIDs(0, null, numPlatformsArray);
        int numPlatforms = numPlatformsArray[0];

        // Obtain a platform ID
        cl_platform_id platforms[] = new cl_platform_id[numPlatforms];
        clGetPlatformIDs(platforms.length, platforms, null);
        cl_platform_id platform = platforms[platformIndex];

        // Initialize the context properties
        cl_context_properties contextProperties = new cl_context_properties();
        contextProperties.addProperty(CL_CONTEXT_PLATFORM, platform);

        // Obtain the number of devices for the platform
        int numDevicesArray[] = new int[1];
        clGetDeviceIDs(platform, deviceType, 0, null, numDevicesArray);
        int numDevices = numDevicesArray[0];

        // Obtain a device ID 
        cl_device_id devices[] = new cl_device_id[numDevices];
        clGetDeviceIDs(platform, deviceType, numDevices, devices, null);
        cl_device_id device = devices[deviceIndex];

        // Create a context for the selected device
        cl_context context = clCreateContext(
            contextProperties, 1, new cl_device_id[]{device}, 
            null, null, null);

        // Create a command-queue for the selected device
        cl_command_queue commandQueue = 
            clCreateCommandQueue(context, device, 0, null);

        // Allocate the memory objects for the input- and output data
        cl_mem memObjects[] = new cl_mem[3];
        memObjects[0] = clCreateBuffer(context, 
            CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR,
            Sizeof.cl_float * n, srcA, null);
        memObjects[1] = clCreateBuffer(context, 
            CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR,
            Sizeof.cl_float * n, srcB, null);
        memObjects[2] = clCreateBuffer(context, 
            CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, 
            Sizeof.cl_float * n, null, null);

        // Create the program from the source code
        cl_program program = clCreateProgramWithSource(context,
            1, new String[]{ programSource }, null, null);

        // Build the program
        clBuildProgram(program, 0, null, null, null, null);

        // Create the kernel
        cl_kernel kernel = clCreateKernel(program, "matrixMul", null);

        long time = nanoTime();
        // Set the arguments for the kernel
        clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, 
            Sizeof.cl_mem, Pointer.to(memObjects[0]));
        clSetKernelArg(kernel, 1, 
            Sizeof.cl_mem, Pointer.to(memObjects[1]));
        clSetKernelArg(kernel, 2, 
            Sizeof.cl_mem, Pointer.to(memObjects[2]));

        // Set the work-item dimensions
        long global_work_size[] = new long[]{n};
        long local_work_size[] = new long[]{1};


        // Execute the kernel
        clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(commandQueue, kernel, 2, null,
            global_work_size, local_work_size, 0, null, null);

        // Read the output data
        clEnqueueReadBuffer(commandQueue, memObjects[2], CL_TRUE, 0,
            n * Sizeof.cl_float, dst, 0, null, null);

        time = nanoTime() - time;
        System.out.println("GPU time: "+ time +"ns " + (time/1000000)+"ms");

        // Release kernel, program, and memory objects
        clReleaseMemObject(memObjects[0]);
        clReleaseMemObject(memObjects[1]);
        clReleaseMemObject(memObjects[2]);
        clReleaseKernel(kernel);
        clReleaseProgram(program);
        clReleaseCommandQueue(commandQueue);
        clReleaseContext(context);

        // Verify the result
        boolean passed = true;
        final float epsilon = 1e-7f;
        for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
            float x = dstArray[i];
            float y = srcArrayA[i] * srcArrayB[i];
            boolean epsilonEqual = Math.abs(x - y) <= epsilon * Math.abs(x);
            if (!epsilonEqual)
            {
                passed = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Test "+(passed?"PASSED":"FAILED"));
        if (n <= 128)
        {
            System.out.println("Result: "+java.util.Arrays.toString(dstArray));
        }
    }
}
```

My question is, what is the right global_work_size and local_work_size of Matrix Multiplication with the size of [1024 x 1024], [2048 x 2048], [4096 x 4096] and [8192 x 8192]?

Here's the code in global_work_size and local_work_size that cause the error

```
// Set the work-item dimensions
        long global_work_size[] = new long[]{n};
        long local_work_size[] = new long[]{1};


// Execute the kernel
        clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(commandQueue, kernel, 2, null,
        global_work_size, local_work_size, 0, null, null);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assigning the work_dim argument in clEnqueueNDRange to 2. But then the size of the global-size array you pass is 1 (you initialize it with a single value). It's bombing because it expects the array to have 2 entries.
The work_dim field specifies your dimension of global work items, not the dimensions of the data array. So set work_dim field (3rd argument) to 1.

Comment: Thanks @Hashman! I changed it to 1 but now another error come up. Here it is: 'Exception in thread "main" org.jocl.CLException: CL_INVALID_KERNEL_ARGS
 at org.jocl.CL.checkResult(CL.java:787)
 at org.jocl.CL.clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(CL.java:20802)
 at org.jocl.samples.JOCLSample.main(JOCLSample.java:150)' 

I don't get it why the kernel arguments are invalid..

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are using shared local memory, the async_copy functions, or checking get_local_id for some other reason, you don't need to set the local work group size and you can let the driver select one (by passing NULL). Once you get things working correctly, you can try passing different values to see if it changes performance, but be aware that the global size needs to be an integer multiple of the local size, so if that will make it larger than your real work size, you'll have to add a condition in your kernel to skip the boundary cases.

Comment: Thanks @Dithemaster! I did changed the local_work_size to null.. And now another Error occurred, it says CL_INVALID_KERNEL_ARGS: 
'Exception in thread "main" org.jocl.CLException: CL_INVALID_KERNEL_ARGS
 at org.jocl.CL.checkResult(CL.java:787)
 at org.jocl.CL.clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(CL.java:20802)
 at org.jocl.samples.JOCLSample.main(JOCLSample.java:146)'

I don't know what should be the correct kernel arguments in this situation.